# Email problem in Outlook 554 5.2.0 SubmissionQuotaExceededException

Tags: email

My system sends emails via PHP to the users on my website, but as of lately none of my mails will send and I will get the following error:

> 554 5.2.0
>   STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SubmissionQuotaExceededException; Failed
>   to process message due to a permanent exception with message The
>   message can't be submitted because the sender's submission quota was
>   exceeded. SubmissionQuotaExceededException: The message can't be
>   submitted because the sender's submission quota was exceeded.
>   [Hostname=xxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]  Tegengehouden door een
>   SMTP-foutmelding: 554 5.2.0
>   STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SubmissionQuotaExceededException; Failed
>   to process message due to a permanent exception with message The
>   message can't be submitted because the sender's submission quota was
>   exceeded. SubmissionQuotaExceededException: The message can't be
>   submitted because the sender's submission quota was exceeded.
>   [Hostname=xxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

I've been Googling it like there's no tomorrow (i think i've read every page in the first 3 google results pages). And I cannot seem to find a solution to this.

These are the things I checked:

1. None of the mail boxes are full (the email addresses where we sent the mails via PHP from are respectively 1.9/50GB and 2.6/50GB full).
2. I can still send emails manually from both these email addresses when using the outlook web client
3. I am not an admin so I cannot run the message tracer to get an exact amount of emails that I am sending [message tracer](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results). But it definitely is not over 10k per day or 30/minute.

Note: the error is **554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SubmissionQuotaExceededException** . Most of the results on google for the 554 5.2.0 error contain the following error message "STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied", this is **NOT** the case for me.

Comment: Make sure the message size is below the limit.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko where do I find out the size allowed and the size of my message?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=UqOTXJHaINL5-wSc5ozQDQ&q=outlook.com+max+message+size&oq=outlook.com+max+mess&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i22i30l5.864.6844..9042...0.0..0.116.1564.20j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i131j0j0i10j0i22i10i30.X1LVlf7HTfI

Comment: @Dennis Did you get a solution to this issue

Comment: Nope never figured it out... I put a large timeout between my mails being sent and it still happens occassionaly, but less frequently.. I'm slowly transitioning my emails to a third party (sendgrid) now.